# Set SLF4J binding dynamically

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logback, slf4j, java.util.logging

I am developing an application for Google App Engine. GAE uses JUL for logging. However, when developing locally, I would still prefer to use SLF4J+logback. I am trying to accomplish this by using SLF4J and different bindings (`slf4j-jdk14` for GAE and logback for local development). The problem is that I have to manually change dependencies when building, which is a pain.

Is it possible to dynamically set binding, depending on whether the app is running on the cloud or locally?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you build with maven you can use profiles to change dependencies dynaically

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        ...
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.25</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        ...
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.7</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```